# Как из ячейки в google таблицах или эксель переместить часть данных в соседнюю по формуле?

Tags: excel, google-spreadsheet, excel-формулы

Есть таблица, в таблице есть ячейка с название товара, прямо в названии указан пол, цвет и тип (обувь).
https://yadi.sk/i/IGamLLN43XsZRL

Суть вопроса - нужна формула, с помощью которой можно выделить определенное слово, например Womens и перенести его в соседнюю ячейку, так же поступить с другим словами. Можно не за один раз.
Полагаю реализовать можно по принципу ЕСЛИ ТО (if then else).
Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь или указание куда смотреть.

Пример данных:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12fyo4Nhxqmjvjp_AJn0Mng3clqtuh_XFtJK3kUNU8RQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Но цвет, тип и пол могут быть описаны разными словами или словосочетаниями. Нужно иметь списки слов и сверяться с ними. Или искать по позиции в тексте, если эта позиция не меняется или ее можно огически отследить. Для того, чтобы получать помощь здесь, нужно показывать, что не получается.

Comment: Вы правы, нужно иметь список слов. Цвет может быть как Black, так и Yellow и тп, пол только Womens, Mens или Couple, типов так же несколько. Можно пройтись несколько раз, мне бы принцип понять. Скажем, я никогда не сталкивался с такими задачами в таблицах, возможно уже есть на эту темы статьи или ветки на форумах, но мне не удалось найти.

Comment: Без Ваших примеров - формула массива, которая определяет, есть ли словосочетание в списке. Или макросом. Логика та же. Прикрепите пример данных к вопросу, покажите примеры списков. *Excel* и *Google*-таблицы хоть и похожи, но различия есть. Решение к одной программе может быть неприменимо в другой

Comment: Перенести - означает удалить из текста и вставить в ячейку. Вам же нужно копировать?

Comment: Перенести имеется ввиду вырезать и вставить в другую ячейку

Comment: Тогда формулы бессильны. только в коде